# T4 templates calling wrong System.Web.Mvc.DLL version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on an ongoing MVC project and I find the following persistent error whenever I try to run the T4 templates:

```
Error   12  Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
File name: 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at T4MvcJs.RoutesHandler.UrlGenerator..ctor(RouteCollection routes)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingF72A8112BFEB9F17586767C84F7FB5505CA3E6317EBC7A05A78C1F9519501C6B559CE92433BE1C72A2FB157C3DB6B667A6A07F1D831AD0C197A51F899279EB8D.GeneratedTextTransformation.SetupRoutes() in c:\work\WebClient\Scripts\T4MvcJs\T4MvcJs.tt:line 211
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingF72A8112BFEB9F17586767C84F7FB5505CA3E6317EBC7A05A78C1F9519501C6B559CE92433BE1C72A2FB157C3DB6B667A6A07F1D831AD0C197A51F899279EB8D.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() in c:\work\WebClient\Scripts\T4MvcJs\T4MvcJs.tt:line 33

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : T4MvcJs.RoutesHandler, Version=0.7.30.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\cperez\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\devenv.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/work/WebClient/packages/T4MvcJs.1.0.13/tools/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/work/WebClient/packages/T4MvcJs.1.0.13/tools/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/work/WebClient/packages/T4MvcJs.1.0.13/tools/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/work/WebClient/packages/T4MvcJs.1.0.13/tools/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
    c:\work\WebClient\Scripts\T4MvcJs\T4MvcJs.tt    211 1   WebClient
```

I've reinstalled Mvc, I've reinstalled VS 2013, I've installed VS2013 Service Pack 5 and I get the same error every single time. My project's web.config, btw, has this regarding System.Web.Mvc:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

And this is the assembly info in my devenv.exe.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
    <codeBase version="5.0.0.0" href="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Web\Razor\v3.0\MVC5.0\System.Web.Mvc.dll"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

I'm at the end of my wits with this...

Comment: Got the same problem... Have you found any solution?